# How to append data on jquery script from php/html form?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a html table script i found online using JQuery. And another script that uses html and JavaScript.

- script1 - send input from a html form to html table using JQuery.
- script2 - has data inside a html table that pings my online websites
  to check status using javascript.

i have to edit script2 in notepad++ to insert the websites url/IPs in order to use it. I want to use script1 to input the data to script2 table. But im having some issues with identifying what im doing wrong. Im not getting any errors, i'm not getting any results either.

- TABLE id on script2 is pinger
- TABLE class on script1 is table-bordered data-table
- Div class on script1 is form-group
- Div id on script2 is content
  Im not sure if that matters. I tried looking up div class and div id usage - what i understand is their both do the same thing. 
  On script2 the the table row has:

  ```
  <td><span>DNSPod DNS</span> (119.29.29.29)</td>
  <td class='latency' id='**us-east-1**' endpoint='**119.29.29.29**'>&nbsp;</td>
  ```

  **us-east-1** is what i want to replace with name
  **119.29.29.29** is what i want to replace with ip

[script1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr5uy.png)

[scrip2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkPLu.png)

on script1 JQuery is:

```
     $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    var ip = $("input[name='ip']").val();

    $(".data-table tbody").append("<tr data-name='"+name+"' data-ip='"+ip+"'><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+ip+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");

    $("input[name='name']").val('');
    $("input[name='ip']").val('');
});

$("body").on("click", ".btn-delete", function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});

$("body").on("click", ".btn-edit", function(){
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name');
    var ip = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-ip');

    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").html('<input name="edit_name" value="'+name+'">');
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").html('<input name="edit_ip" value="'+ip+'">');

    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(2)").prepend("<button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-update'>Update</button><button class='btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-cancel'>Cancel</button>")
    $(this).hide();
});

$("body").on("click", ".btn-cancel", function(){
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name');
    var ip = $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-ip');

    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(name);
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text(ip);

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-edit").show();
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-update").remove();
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-cancel").remove();
});

$("body").on("click", ".btn-update", function(){
    var name = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name='edit_name']").val();
    var ip = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name='edit_ip']").val();

    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text(name);
    $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text(ip);

    $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-name', name);
    $(this).parents("tr").attr('data-ip', ip);

    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-edit").show();
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-cancel").remove();
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".btn-update").remove();
});
```

i want to use script1 to input data into the table in script1 and use the js code in script2 to ping the servers.

This is what i have so far but it doesn't work

```
    $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    var ip = $("input[name='ip']").val();
    $(".data-table tbody").append("<tr data-name='"+name+"' data-ip='"+ip+"'><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+ip+"</td><td class='latency'  id='"+name+"' endpoint='"+ip+"'>&nbsp;</td><td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't close the submit method? (I added the last line of the code below to close the method)

```
   $("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
    var ip = $("input[name='ip']").val();

    $(".data-table tbody").append("<tr data-name='"+name+"' data-ip='"+ip+"'>"+
    "<td>"+name+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+ip+"</td>"+
    "<td class='latency' id='"+name+"' endpoint='"+ip+"'>&nbsp;</td>"+
    "<td>"+
      "<button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button>"+
      "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button>"+
    "</td>"+
  "</tr>");
});
```

Comment: both script1 & script2 works well however after closing the and as you mentioned the new form to input the data       . <td><span>$name</span> ($address)</td>
<td class='latency' id='$name' endpoint='$address'>&nbsp;</td>        .does not work. the form updates the vars but it wont ping